# EditText password input doesnt pan the window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have some EditTexts in a LinearLayout , the one that I set the inputtype to password is at the bottom of the screen, when I click on it and it gets focus, the keyboard come up and covers it.
when all of EditTexts get focus and the keyboard shows up, they pan the screen except the one that has password for its input type. can I fix it in xml?
whats the easiest soliution?

Comment: android:imeOption="actionNext" and for password android:imeOption="actionDone" if it is the last then actionNext

Answer (score 2):

need to add this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your manifests file in the activity tag

like this :

```
      <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
              />
```